# Unclickable area on second monitor, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

There is an area on the lower left corner of my 2nd screen which is unclickable, regardless of whatever software is displayed on the screen.

The unclickable area is approximately around 260px wide and 60px tall, stuck to the very bottom left of the second screen.

I couldn't find either an explanation of a similar problem, or a solution about that. I'd appreciate any suggestions or a solution.

*Side note:* I'm using Windows taskbar on top and locked.

Display arrangement on Windows settings:
[image: Display arrangement on Windows settings]

[DxDiag Output](https://pastebin.com/zzAYPJrs)

Software specifications:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 17763)
- System model: MS-7B33
- BIOS: 1.40
- DirectX 12

Hardware specifications:

- First monitor: LG 24MK400H-B 23.6" 1920x1080 @ 75Hz
- Second monitor: AOC 24B1H 23.6" 1920x1080 @ 60Hz
- Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
- Processor: Intel Core i5-8500 @ 3.00GHz (6 Cores)
- Memory: 16GB (16384MB) RAM

Comment: Might be a hardware problem. Try it when booting in Safe mode.

Comment: It's related to the notifications in the lower right (even though your taskbar could possibly be only on one monitor). I still haven't isolated what's causing it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution myself.

After doing some research, I came across with a program named "Windows Process Explorer" and I was able to drag and drop an instance over the weirdly acting area.

Finally, I've figured out that the process name was "TWCU.exe", which was created by TP-Link devices.

Comment: This has been bugging me for MONTHS, and i never bothered to figure it out, id just go move the screen to my other monitor.

Comment: @KySoto I'm more of a perfectionist person, so I had to solve that problem. And the fact that I found that program to analyze what was causing it by some graphical interface, was a great discovery for me. It didn't only solve that, it also helped me with other stuff like finding out a window's container name and etc.

Comment: Thats awesome. I didn't realize you could use process explorer like that, and I've been using that since windows xp.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue, although I'm using a Windows 10 Laptop as a second screen. In my case, the Laptop has the dead area. Unplugging and plugging the monitor seems to solve the issue for a few days.

Changing which monitor is the main monitor also seems to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing second display position slightly from settings. That helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue in windows 11 and fixed it

1. downloaded sysinternalas process explorer
2. onmce installed, used the Target button and dragged to the area where I cant click
3. it highlighed the exe minihostsearch.exe
4. I killed that executable
5. I can click at the bottom now